# \date command - replacing "Date:" by something else

Tags: datetime, amsart

I'm using `\documentclass{amsart}`. In the `tex` file, before `\maketitle` I write `\date{22th october 2012}`, and then I obtain "Date: 22th october 2012." as a result.

Using `\date`, I want it to print "London, 22th october 2012.". How can I do that?

I tried `\renewcommand{\date}`, but maybe the right thing to do is to change `\the@date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine `\datename` to suppress the string "Date:"

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\renewcommand{\datename}{}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\date{London, 22th october 2012}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]